# is there anyway to run .py in another pc with no python installation package (PIP)

Tags: python

I am newbie at code I made a shutdown that will run music and it will perfect shutdown with the music
but the problem is my friend want to use it but he dont want to use PIP install (i dont know why)
and is there anyway to Run .py in another pc with no PIP or is there anyway to run without PIP

```
import os 
import time
import subprocess
import pyautogui
import sys
import win32gui, win32con
from PIL import ImageGrab

pyautogui.hotkey('winleft', 'd')

time.sleep(1)

script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
rel_path = "ex/Volume.mp3"
abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)
os.startfile(abs_file_path)

time.sleep(2)

pyautogui.hotkey('winleft', 'd')

script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
rel_path = "ex/Sys.vbs"
abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)
os.startfile(abs_file_path)

time.sleep(5)

os.system("taskkill /f /im wscript.exe")

pyautogui.hotkey('winleft', 'd')

script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
rel_path = "ex/Image.jpg"
abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)
os.startfile(abs_file_path)

time.sleep(0.1)

hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_MAXIMIZE)

time.sleep(0.1)

script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
rel_path = "ex.vbs"
abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)
os.startfile(abs_file_path)

time.sleep(0.2)

hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
win32gui.MoveWindow(hwnd, 830, 800, 200, 100, True)
bbox = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox)

time.sleep(4.8)

COMMAND  = """(New-Object -comObject Shell.Application).Windows() | foreach-object {$_.quit()}; Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne \"\"} | stop-process; Stop-Computer"""
subprocess.run(['powershell', '-command', COMMAND], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the application to an executable using [Pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/), to run without installing python or pip.

a good GUI interface for it is implemented in [auto-py-to-exe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/), but it is good for a one-time conversion, not for continuous development.

note that he has to have powershell installed on his pc to run your code.

another alternative is to package the libraries inside a virtual environment, but i'll let someone else make this answer with detail.